# how can i use a slot inside a v-for to customize each column of a data-table?

Tags: vue.js, v-for, v-slot, vuetify-datatable

in this example of vuetify documentation for data-tables as described 
<strike>[here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#header)</strike>, to customize the calories column we’re using the item.calories slot:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:item.calories="{ item }">
        <v-chip
          :color="getColor(item.calories)"
          dark
        >
          {{ item.calories }}
        </v-chip>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

but i need v-for to customize all the columns, so that it can be something like:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <v-for :list="headers">
        <template v-slot:item.header="{ item }">
          <v-chip
            :color="getColor(item.header)"
            dark
          >
            {{ item.calories }}
          </v-chip>
        </template>
       </v-for>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this is not working.

Does anybody know how can I deal with this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use the `item` slot where you can freely put TR and whatever TD you need. Of course you should order your TDs in the same order as listed in the `headers` prop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can acheive that by using the 'slot' prop instead of the v-slot directive as the following example:

```
<v-chip
 v-for="header in headers" 
 :key="header.value" 
 :slot="`item.${header.value}`" 
 slot-scope="{item}"
>
    {{ item[header.value] }}
</v-chip>
```

note that you should replace teh value key that I'm using with the identifier key of each column object in your code.

Answer (score 1):

This works also within the `<template>` (we are using this in Vue 2). There is no need for the `slot` prop:

```js
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts" :items-per-page="5" class="elevation-1">
      <template v-for="header in headers" #[`item.${header.value}`]="{value}">
        {{ value + " foo" }}
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/StefanBrand/pen/vYQemre

Comment: This is a brilliant solution if you need to have X-amount of headers with 'almost' the same behaviour.